# Flex ColumnChart label is getting truncated (example included)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, charts

I can't seem to figure out why, but the label on my ColumnSeries always seems to get truncated regardless of how wide the column is. I've tried setting the labelSizeLimit to an arbitrarily large number, but that doesn't seem to help

Any ideas as to whats going on?

Here is some sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mx:Application name="BarChart_barWidthRatio_test"
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="vertical"
    verticalAlign="middle"
    backgroundColor="white">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function labelFunc(v1:Object, v2:Object):String {

                return 'asdfasasds';

            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

<mx:ArrayCollection id="arrColl">
    <mx:source>
        <mx:Array>
            <mx:Object name="R Winn" obp=".353" slg=".445" avg=".300" />
            <mx:Object name="P Feliz" obp=".290" slg=".418" avg=".253" />
            <mx:Object name="O Vizquel" obp=".305" slg=".316" avg=".246" />
            <mx:Object name="B Molina" obp=".298" slg=".433" avg=".276" />
            <mx:Object name="R Durham" obp=".295" slg=".343" avg=".218" />
        </mx:Array>
    </mx:source>
</mx:ArrayCollection>

<mx:ApplicationControlBar dock="true">
    <mx:Form>
        <mx:FormItem label="barWidthRatio:">
            <mx:HSlider id="slider"
                    minimum="0.0"
                    maximum="1.0"
                    value="0.6"
                    liveDragging="true"
                    tickInterval="0.1" />
        </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:Form>
</mx:ApplicationControlBar>

 <mx:ColumnChart id="barChart"
         showDataTips="true"
         dataProvider="{arrColl}"
         width="100%"
         height="100%">
      <mx:horizontalAxis>
       <mx:CategoryAxis 
            dataProvider="{arrColl}" 
            categoryField="name"
       />
    </mx:horizontalAxis>

    <mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:LinearAxis minimum="0" maximum="1"/>
    </mx:verticalAxis>    

    <mx:series>
        <mx:ColumnSeries id="barSeries"
                yField="avg"
                xField="name"
                displayName="name"
                labelFunction="{labelFunc}"
                labelPosition="outside"
                labelAlign="center"
                labelSizeLimit="900"
                labelRotation="45"
                columnWidthRatio="{slider.value}" />
    </mx:series>
</mx:ColumnChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you show the labels inside, then it will work.

```
labelPosition="inside"
```

If you want `labelPosition="outside"`, then you need to extend and override label drawing.

========= information below is only FYI, has no relation with the problem/solution ==========
    labelAlign="center"

This is valid when

```
labelPosition="inside"
```

And, `labelSizeLimit` is actually font size threshold. This should not be that high.

Comment: Even without the labelAlign, it seems like an inherit flaw to truncate text so dramatically.

Comment: I mentioned the labelAlign issue only FYI. It has no relation to the solution to your problem. If you use labelPositoin="inside", then the issue is solved. If you want to use labelPosition="outside", you need to extend and override the label drawing

Comment: I have edited the answer for better understanding of what I was trying to say

Comment: Thanks Sarwar..I understood you're original post. My concern is that there seems to be a big flaw that when the position is set to 'outside' the label is truncated so much.

Comment: Whether this is a feature or flaw, you can overcome it by using your own ItemRenderer